# Sheets("New").Select creating new workbook unintentionally

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason, `Sheets.copy` is making another workbook. I don't know how to fix it. I just want it to copy the first `Sheets("New")` and paste everything that I have selected over to a new `Sheets("New(2)")`.

`Sheets.Copy
    Sheets("New").Select
    Sheets("New").Copy After:=Sheet1
'****Copy Assessment Date to the Nourish Report Printable****
    Sheets("New").Select
    Range("C74").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("New (2)").Select
    Range("V96").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste`

Comment: Thank you for the information. Have it bookmarked now. =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the `Sheets` object. In my experience it is better to use the `Worksheets` object.  I would recommend simplifying your code by removing all of the copy and paste / select and just making the cell range take the exact value you want.  The Macro Recorder does not do a very a good job of producing efficient code but it certainly does help with syntax and getting you started.  Consider the code below to accomplish what you want.

```
Sub CopySheet()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, nws As Worksheet

    'set up
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("New")
    'Create a copy of the worksheet
    ws.Copy wb.Worksheets(1) 'places the worksheet at the front
    Set nws = wb.Worksheets(1) 'References the new front worksheet
    'set a name for the new sheet for easy reference
    nws.Name = "newSheet" 'set to whatever name you want
    'Print out the actual value you want rather than copy and paste.
    nws.Range("V96").Value = ws.Range("C74").Value
    nws.Activate 'select the new worksheet

End Sub
```

And here it is without all of the comments

```
Sub CopySheet()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, nws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("New")
    ws.Copy wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set nws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    nws.Name = "newSheet"
    nws.Range("V96").Value = ws.Range("C74").Value

End Sub
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you so much!